# How to download multiple HTML tables to Excel using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page where multiple HTML tables are there...I need to download all the HTML tables to *Microsoft Excel*.
With the current coding I have I can download the first table but I need to download all the tables.

This is the JavaScript which I have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
```

And this is the portion of the PHP where the table is populated:

```
<div id="render_me">

<table width='100%' id="testTable">
<col width="15%" />
        <col width="10%" />
    <col width="25%" />
<col width="15%" />
    <col width="10%" />
<col width="15%" />
    <col width="10%" />
<tr>
<th><?php echo $b;  //row id ?></th>     
     <th class='forcedWidth1'>Merk</th>     
<th class='forcedWidth1'>Artikel naam</th>
<th>EAN</th>
    <th>Prijs Kieskeurig.nl</th>    
    <th>Verschil Kieskeurig.nl</th>
    <th>RAL Prijs</th>
  </tr>
    <?php 
  while($row=mysql_fetch_object($sql)):?>
  <tr>
<td width:'90px'></td>
<td class='forcedWidth1'><?php echo $row->merk;  //row id ?></td>  
<td class='forcedWidth1'><?php echo (utf8_decode($row->OM));  //row id ?></td>  
<td class='forcedWidth'><?php echo(utf8_decode("<a href=".$row->TW_URL.">".$row->EAN."</a>")); ?></td>
<td class='forcedWidth'><?php $num2 = $row->PRICE; echo number_format($num2,2,'.', ''); ?></td>
    <td class='forcedWidth'><?php $num6 = $num2 - $row->RAL; echo number_format($num6, 2, '.', ''); // row first name ?></td>
    <td class='forcedWidth'><?php echo $row->RAL; // row first name ?></td>

  </tr>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</table>



<?php } }?>
<?php }?>
<button id="btnExport" class="button2"></button> <button onclick="demoPDF()" class="button1">  
            </button> 

</div>
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want multiple xls files, or one xls file with tabs, one per table?

Comment: No one excel file with all the tables...

Comment: If you want to grab them all, you'll need to either change the button to look for multiple ID's, or change it to look for a class that is on multiple tables instead.   If you can use jquery, it would be easier to write with it's $.each() command.

Comment: I have used jquery with the following code:<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnExport").click(function () {
            $("#render_me").btechco_excelexport({
                containerid: "render_me"
               , datatype: $datatype.Table
            });
        });
    });
</script> the library i have used is here http://wsnippets.com/export-html-table-data-excel-sheet-using-jquery/

Comment: but its giving me error

Comment: You can edit your post to add the additional code.  It's much more readable that way than squeezed into a comment line.